# Parse the JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I Have following JSON data, I need to iterate this data based on ***Keytype*** in JAVASCRIPT.
It should return record from only the passed key code.
Say i need record  from 438 means it should give me only following data.
(ex:"K": "43800001", "D": "Data1")

```
{
  "GroupCode": {
    "PickType": [
      {
        "@KeyType": "438",
        "R": [
          {
            "K": "43800001",
            "D": "Data1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@KeyType": "439",
        "R": [
          {
            "K": "43900001",
            "D": "Data2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@KeyType": "440",
        "R": [
          {
            "K": "44000001",
            "D": "Data3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@KeyType": "441",
        "R": [
          {
            "K": "44100001",
            "D": "Data4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

as I'm not good in java script and new to it, i haven't tried coding for this. Please help me in getting the data.

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) parses JSON

Comment: you should try, not put it directly

Comment: @JaromandaX Why would he needs to parse it? It is already js object in valid JSON format

Comment: I assumed from the question TITLE - my bad

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh ya, then it would be the answer ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35200198/5678086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say the above is stored in a variable `obj`. You can get the result via following

```
var result = obj.GroupCode.PickType.filter(function(item){
                return item["@KeyType"] === "438"
            }).map(function(item){
               return item.R[0];
            });
```

**Please note**, `result` is an `array`. If you have unique object against the condition then for that you will have to check the length of array and then extract the object i.e. `result[0]` or `result.shift()`

Comment: Very close but returns an array. OP wants `.map(...)[0]`

Comment: @A.Wolff - I was editing the answer with comments. Thank you

Comment: That's said, you don't need to map it: `obj.GroupCode.PickType.filter(function(item){
                return item["@KeyType"] === "438"
            })[0].R[0];`  But somehow, your code is more readable

Comment: @A.Wolff - I wish that was an answer so that I can upvote it :)

Comment: @nikil What is the purpose of item in filter function here

Comment: @ViKu - Ignore my previous comment. `item` is basically your object in the array. `filter` function checks every object of the array and then filters the result based on matched criteria

Comment: @nikil - Thanks for your reply nikil, if suppose i have two or more data( ex: "K":"44100001", "D": "Data4") Inside R, will it return me the Two or more value?

Comment: @ViKu - The current solution wont as we are returning `item.R[0]` i.e. the 1st item in the array. If you need all the values then you need to return `item.R`

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple jquery each loop and a if:

jquery:

```
$.each(obj.GroupCode.PickType,function(i,v){
 if (v["@KeyType"] == 438) {
      console.log(v.R)//v.R[0];
   }
});
```

javascript:

```
for(v in obj.GroupCode.PickType) {
  if (v["@KeyType"] == 438) {
      console.log(v.R)//v.R[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: warning here, `$.each` is not a vanilla javascript , it comes with jQuery: a js lib. do not take it for granted knowledge. also op said he's new in javascript so maybe he'll get an error while testing your code and wondering "..why?", add some additional info

Comment: eveything is possible, thank you for the edit and for the burning reply

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/sc52pa59/)

```
function getByKeyType(keytype) {
  for(i in f.GroupCode.PickType) {
    if(f.GroupCode.PickType[i].KeyType == keytype) {
       return f.GroupCode.PickType[i].R[0];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

alert(getByKeyType(438).K)
alert(getByKeyType(438).D)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  function getByKeyType(keytype) {
    for(i in f.GroupCode.PickType) {
    if(f.GroupCode.PickType[i].KeyType == keytype) {
       return f.GroupCode.PickType[i].R[0];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: No, it won't work. `var result = JSON.parse(obj);` I think `obj` in OP's code is already an object